# Thumbs_Up Gem with Rails: Problems with `Having`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the `thumbs_up` gem for voting and am getting the following SQL error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING: SELECT "rules".* FROM "rules" HAVING plusminus_tally >= 100
```

I have the following definitions in my controller:

```
  @rules = Rule.where(approved: true).plusminus_tally.order("plusminus_tally DESC")
  @manrules = Rule.having('plusminus_tally >= 100')
  @manguidelines = Rule.having('plusminus_tally < 100')
```

The error is called on my `erb` here:

```
  <% @manruless.each do |rule| %>  <<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
    ...
  <% end %>
```

Just for comparison's sake, I tried it with `@rules` instead of `@manrules` and it worked fine, so the only error should be in my controller statements using `having`.  Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching this from a statement in the `controller` to an `if` statement in the view itself:

```
<% if rule.plusminus_tally >= 100 %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if this is the "Ruby-est" way to do it, but it got the job done on this occasion...